# Nwjs Localization, shows Japanese characters as boxes?

Tags: node.js

I am using Node.js, on SUSE. When system language is Japanese (my locale is `ja_JP.UTF-8`), node shows
Japnese characters as square boxes (For links to Japanese website)

Even tried i18n localization, with properties files for Japenese language.
Node displays all Japanese fonts as boxes. `Window.Navigator.language` does show "`ja`".
And things works great when language is English or French.
I tried different fonts but observed the similar issue.

Comment: Did you have the fonts that are set in Japanese. I had similar issues when working with Java Swing when I saw the fonts missing.

Comment: _Node_ isn't displaying anything.  What are you looking at, the browser? The log?

Answer (score 0):

re-searching for multilingual IDE (integrated development environment) i am wanting to build, and it would seem Japanese has a few competing formats, which are not utf-8,   the kanji / ganji (spelling) has more letters / symbols than other written languages. and a few sites noted competing formats in japan other that utf notations.

http://icu-project.org/ gets data from http://cldr.unicode.org/ from what i understand a lot of software unix / linux / microsoft other big companies use the data. looking at chrome and nodejs, i saw notations of Japanese in a license file. but beyond that i did not find much more info.  the cldr site seems iffy on amount of data for japan compared to other languages when skim reading over handful of files to see what data was in the cldr core files.

with above said, make sure you are setting the html header utf-8 correctly, see if a lang tag works

```
< span lang="jp">some text here</span>
```

i do not know were i read it, it was not kanjo (spelling) but i want to say ganji? (spelling) or rather the "vertical" reading not left to right, or right to left, but vertical reading (from top -> down). and to get things to display correctly it was being placed into "square boxes".